# Script that will check if ajax function will be executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to add an ajax function to my website that will show my visitors an image. How do I make sure that my site visitors will always see an image even though the script failed? Like in cases where they have an unsupported jQuery browser, javascript off, and so on...

Comment: hardcode a placeholder image in html and then use jquery to replace that image

Comment: abluejelly basically has the solution.  Just no javascript I'll edit their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly without knowing the use case I can't understand why you'd need an ajax call to do this:

> <img id="imgID" src="the-image-guaranteed.png" alt="this img doesn't need a lib" />

And then have your library call adjust what the src is if that's the wrong src.

How to select it:
Place this Javascript in the AJAX success handler to update the placeholder image to what you want based on country

```
document.getElementById("imgID").src = newimagesource;
```

Edit was suggested using jQ. Stop using jQ if you can trivially do it with native js. You don't need the overhead.

Comment: I'm showing the visitor a different image based on his country

Comment: Ah alright. I'd personally suggest doing so server-side, rather than shoehorning dynamic content in when someone doesn't want to run js. Most people who disable js understand what they're disabling. Regardless, that kills my ability to really help here. You might be able to bs something with really fancy CSS once we get that parent selector they're working on, but until then, I have to bow out, as I'm not overly versed in AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML tag `<noscript>` to place a default image for the user in the use cases of JavaScript is not enabled.

Then you would need a test function to see if the jQuery libraries are available:

```
 if(jQuery().libraryName) {
   //run library based code
 }
```

Then you update the image however you like (based on the ajax function requirement) within the jQuery library based code section:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "pictureupdate.js",
  dataType: "script"
});
```

Hope this helps!